Exporting 3D models through QGIS
I created a 3D model that contains the DEM, some wind turbine features (.shp) and a boundary area (.shp).
I added an XYZ tile.
I would like to know if there is any way to export the product as a whole. The QGIS viewer allows me to export as .obj, but I don't know how to process these files.
Has anyone gone through something similar? Or do you know of any environment that can represent the model in a fluid way?

Have a look at the Qgis2threejs plugin (https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs) export could be manipulated in a web browser (there some other export format)

Unfortunately the Qgis2threejs plugin reduces model quality. Its output is simple and would be great if it weren't for the quality

See if Blender can do what you need.
I once designed a home in SweetHome3D. Importing its OBJ export into Blender allowed me to do much more than I needed (add videos to TV screens, add sound sources, create a walk-through video).
An awesome tool if you don't mind a bit of a learning curve.
